# How to check if user input is an url?

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a small side project using the steam api, I want to check if the user inputs an url or not.

Could not find anything to this specific problem so if anyone knows that help!

Comment: What is the rule that tells you whether something is a url or not? Does the site have to actually exist? Does it need to refer to an actually existing TLD? Or just what? More importantly, *why does your code care*?

Comment: There is no [tag:python] in this question. See [ask], what is on-topic in the [help/on-topic], and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: See [**`urllib.parse`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)

Comment: I would be curious to know how to use `urllib.parse` for this @PeterWood. It seems like `urllib.parse.urlparse` will accept anything. Is there some validator in there?

Comment: @Mark the question doesn’t say anything about validation.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use regex

Sample Code Below:

```py
import re
regex = r"(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,        <>?«»“”‘’]))"

def is_url(input_string):

    return re.match(regex, input_string):
```

Comment: Seems pretty forgiving given that `is_url("http://---- Not a URL ---")` returns `True`. Maybe that's a *technically* valid URL (almost everything is), but most people wouldn't think so since domains can't start with a `-`.

Comment: @Mark Hey mark it's just the way I showed.... He supposed to make valid regex for his use case.